# current activity screen shot and share it with share icon in action bar

Tags: android, android-activity, screenshot

I want to take current activity screenshot and share it on `share item` click in actionbar share button. When I run application nothing would be shown me as a output. How can I take current screen screenshot? please tell me the proper sequence of it.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item:

            try{
                takeScreenShot(av); // av is instance of hello
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


public static void shoot(Activity a,String b) {
    //savePic(takeScreenShot(a), "sdcard/xx.png");
    savePic(takeScreenShot(a), b);
}
private static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity)
{
    View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
    Rect frame = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
    int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
    int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height  - statusBarHeight);
    view.destroyDrawingCache();
    return b;
}
private static void savePic(Bitmap b, String strFileName)
{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(strFileName);
        if (null != fos)
        {
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that allowed my screenshot to be stored on sd card and used later for whatever your needs are:

First, add proper permission to save file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And this is the code (running in an Activity):

```
        private void takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            openScreenshot(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is how you can open the recently generated image:

```
    private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/4342876